# "Sessionless" et "Sessionful"

Tags: informatique, terminologie, jargon

Exemples:

> **sessionless** web application
>
> **sessionful** web service

Existe-t-il des équivalents courts et élégants pour ces deux termes techniques ?

Comment: Sans sessions, avec sessions ?

Comment: Pas mieux, sauf que je le mettrai au singulier pour ma part, car si session il y a (pour un utilisateur), il n'y en a qu'une en général.

Comment: Je mettrais plutot avec/sans etat! (pas d'accents sur ce clavier)

Comment: avec/sans état: ça se rapproche, mais c'est plutôt stateful, stateless

Answer (score 4):

Vu que *sessionful* et *sessionless* sont eux-mêmes des inventions récentes en anglais (me semble-t-il), et qu'aucun équivalent français ne s'est dégagé, pourquoi ne pas avoir recours à des néologismes tels que *sessionné* et *non sessionné* qui me paraissent être clairs ?

Si on ne veut ni anglicisme ni néologisme, la seule solution serait une périphrase comme le propose Stéphane Gimenez : *avec sessions, sans sessions*, ou bien, si on veut être tout à fait précis (dans un texte) *avec/sans ouverture automatique de session*.